# Как удалить nofollow из ссылок woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce добавляет к ссылкам товаров rel='nofollow'. Хочу удалить этот атрибут или поменять на dofollow. Нашел фильтр в сети, но он не работает

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_to_cart_dofollow', 10, 2 );
function add_to_cart_dofollow($html, $product){
    $html = sprintf( '%s',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    );
    return $html;
}
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Этот код правит ссылки добавления товаров в корзину (что видно даже из названия хука). Вам где и какие ссылки надо править?

Comment: да, я эти ссылки и имел в виду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_to_cart_dofollow', 10, 2 );

function add_to_cart_dofollow( $html, $product ) {
    return str_replace( 'rel="nofollow"', 'rel="dofollow"', $html );
}
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: А можно сделать то же самое для всех ссылок на сайте? И будет ли это работать со ссылками от плагинов, скриптов и тд?

Comment: Так просто не получится. Есть плагины, массово работающие со ссылками, например https://wordpress.org/plugins/mihdan-no-external-links/. Может, там есть какой-то фильтр. Но это тема для отдельного вопроса.